# Title position of UIBarButton

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, toolbaritems

I want to set my `UIBarButtonItem.title` underneath the `UIBarButton` image.

[image]

I tried using :

```
myBarButton.setTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffset(horizontal: 5,vertical: -5), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
```

the text doesn't show though. Any ideas?
It is not possible for me to integrate `UITabBar` just in case this is your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust your button's title and image with "Size Inspector". Size inspector found in "utilities area".

[image]